# How to read values from json file

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, .net-core

I have a .net core application that is designed to send emails, the email and the password used to send the email is stored in json file. I was able to send emails normally while developing, however when I publish the application couldn't read the email and the password from the json file. Is there any error in the code?

```
public class Startup
{
    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()

            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

     public void ReadFromJson()
    {
            var email = ($"{Configuration["option1"]}");
            var password = ($"{Configuration["option2"]}");
            var path = ($"{Configuration["option3"]}");
            File.WriteAllText("/var/hey.txt",email);
   }
```

Json file (appsettings.json) :

```
   {
    "option1": "something@outlook.com",
    "option2": "something",
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use IConfiguration  to read configuration data

```
IConfiguration _iconfiguration;  
public ConstructorForClass(IConfiguration iconfiguration) {  
  _iconfiguration = iconfiguration;  
}

public void ReadFromJson()
    {
var email =_iconfiguration["option1"];  
var email =_iconfiguration["option1"];  
   }
```

put this into your startup method

```
services.Configure<ClassName>(Configuration);
```

you put ReadFromJson on startup, not a good practice to do, create new class to read data and from that access to where ever you want

Comment: thanks, I rewritten my code and i put it in a class with ReadFromJson method and still it gave me an empty string in the email

Comment: but i used .... services.Configure<MyClassName>(Configuration); instead of service.AddSingleton <IConfiguration> (Configuration);

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use string interoplation here? Did you try

```
var option1 = Configuration.GetValue<string>("option1");
```

Comment: thanks but i still didn't read the values after publishing the application

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        jsonstring = client.DownloadString("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Kokuvil");
        dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);

        Response.Write(dynObj.results[0].address_components[1].long_name);
    }
```